# Gnome-terminal Top Right

Tags: gnome-terminal

Have searched the community without any luck. I have remove and reinstalled the gnome-terminal without success. I'm trying to remove a icon that shows at the top right corner of the gnome-terminal. A different user in the same PC does not have that. I'm sure it has to be some user configuration but I don't know which one. I'm using Debian 9 after importing my home folder from another distro.

[image]

Any suggestions are welcome.